# R programming_ Subsetting rows on logic conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Sample data:

> sampleData

```
Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day sampleData.Ozone

1      41     190  7.4   67     5   1               41

2      36     118  8.0   72     5   2               36

3      12     149 12.6   74     5   3               12
.........
```

Want to extract records on the condition `$ozone > 31`

Here is the code:

```
data <- sampleData[sampleData$ozone > 31]
```

And get the error below:

> Error in if (inherits(X[[j]], "data.frame") && ncol(xj) > 1L) X[[j]] <- as.matrix(X[[j]]) : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

How should I correct it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

R is case sensitive, so your `ozone` has to match the name in your `data.frame`. Also to subset a `data.frame`, you need two indices (row and column) separated by a comma. If there is nothing after the comma, it means that you are selecting all the *columns*:

```
sampleData[sampleData$Ozone > 31,]
```

Other methods to subset a `data.frame`:

```
subset(sampleData, Ozone > 31)
```

or with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
sampleData %>%
  filter(Ozone > 31)
```

**Result:**

```
  Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day sampleData.Ozone
1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1               41
2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2               36
```

**Data:**

```
sampleData = structure(list(Ozone = c(41L, 36L, 12L), Solar.R = c(190L, 118L, 
149L), Wind = c(7.4, 8, 12.6), Temp = c(67L, 72L, 74L), Month = c(5L, 
5L, 5L), Day = 1:3, sampleData.Ozone = c(41L, 36L, 12L)), .Names = c("Ozone", 
"Solar.R", "Wind", "Temp", "Month", "Day", "sampleData.Ozone"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```